# Storage system in Anylogic

Tags: storage, rack, anylogic, warehouse

1. How can I model a "flow through" storage rack in Anylogic? Meaning that the pallets will be stored from one end and be retrieved from the opposite end.
2. How can I model that the shelves in the storage racks have different heights. E.g. one rack have three levels: two shelves are 180cm and one shelf is 160 in the same rack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can't do any of these things with the current pallet racks objects.

The only way is to develop it yourself.

For #1, you can do it with a set of Fixed cell conveyors with some control over the conveyor movement... or a combination of roller conveyor/station ... it depends if each pallet will move independently or in group

For #2 you will have to develop it yourself, but in a way, you can just put the x conveyors i mentionned at customized heights and you are done

That's how i would do it

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you mean gravity racks. I saw a presentation in which anylogic development team confirmed that they are working on those. Not sure by when they will release
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-WytqY1HbY&t=684s
2. Not sure if this is possible

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).